# Sequelize: Find All That Match Contains (Case Insensitive)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I want to use sequelize.js to query a model for records with a contains restraint. How do I do that?

This is what I have right now:

```
Assets
  .findAll({ limit: 10, where: ["asset_name like ?", '%' + request.body.query + '%'] })
  .then(function(assets){
    return response.json({
      msg: 'search results',
      assets: assets
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
```

but I get the following error:

```
   { error: operator does not exist: character varying @> unknown
       at Connection.parseE (/home/travellr/safe-star.com/SafeStar/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
       at Connection.parseMessage (/home/travellr/safe-star.com/SafeStar/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:381:17)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/travellr/safe-star.com/SafeStar/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:22)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
     name: 'error',
     length: 209,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42883',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: 'No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.',
     position: '246',
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'parse_oper.c',
     line: '722',
     routine: 'op_error',
     sql: 'SELECT "id", "asset_name", "asset_code", "asset_icon", "asset_background", "asset_add_view", "asset_add_script", "asset_add_id_regex", "date_created", "uniqueValue", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "assets" AS "assets" WHERE "assets"."asset_name" @> \'%a%\' LIMIT 10;' },
  sql: 'SELECT "id", "asset_name", "asset_code", "asset_icon", "asset_background", "asset_add_view", "asset_add_script", "asset_add_id_regex", "date_created", "uniqueValue", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "assets" AS "assets" WHERE "assets"."asset_name" @> \'%a%\' LIMIT 10;' }
```

How do you use a contains query in sequelize?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
Assets.findAll({
        limit: 10,
        where: {
            asset_name: {
                [Op.like]: '%' + request.body.query + '%'
            }
        }
}).then(function(assets){
    return response.json({
        msg: 'search results',
        assets: assets
    });
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

**EDIT**

In order to make it case insensitive, you could use the `LOWER` sql function, but previously you would also have to lower case your `request.body.query` value. Sequelize query would then look like that

```
let lookupValue = request.body.query.toLowerCase();

Assets.findAll({
    limit: 10,
    where: {
        asset_name: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('asset_name')), 'LIKE', '%' + lookupValue + '%')
    }
}).then(function(assets){
    return response.json({
        msg: 'message',
        assets: assets
    });
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

What it does is to lower case your `asset_name` value from table, as well as lower case the `request.body.query` value. In such a case you compare two lower cased strings.

In order to understand better what is happening in this case I recommend you take a look at the sequelize documentation concerning [**`sequelize.where()`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#whereattr-comparator-logic-sequelizewhere), [**`sequelize.fn()`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#fnfn-args-sequelizefn) as well as [**`sequelize.col()`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#colcol-sequelizecol). Those functions are very useful when trying to perform some unusual queries rather than simple `findAll` or `findOne`.

The `sequelize` in this case is of course your Sequelize instance.

Comment: I have updated the answer, now it should be case insensitive.

Comment: if you're using PG, you can use `[Op.iLike]:  \`%${request.body.query}%\`` and skip the lowercasing cruft.

Comment: hi @piotrbienias, what can I do when I wanna check if asset_name match with one of this string: 'bac', 'rgr', 'afg', 'rtt'. 
something like this: if (asset_name.match(/(bac)|(rgr)|(afg)|(rtt)/)) fetch it.

Comment: How would you do this with multiple columns such as %john% in first_name, last_name & email

Comment: [Op.like] didnt work for me due to error: OP is not defined. But this works very well: 
`asset_name: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('asset_name')), 'LIKE', '%' + lookupValue + '%')
`

Answer (score 35):

If you are using sequlize with Postgres better to use `` [Op.iLike]: `%${request.body.query}%` ``  and you can forget about the sequlize functions.

Comment: Hey, will definitely try that!

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like [Op.iLike] will only work if you're using Postgres https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html

Answer (score 5):

```
// search case insensitive nodejs usnig sequelize


 const sequelize = require('sequelize');
    let search = "Ajay PRAJAPATI"; // what ever you right here
    userModel.findAll({
        where: {
            firstname: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('LOWER', sequelize.col('firstname')), 'LIKE', '%' + search.toLowerCase() + '%')
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

const keyword = "John";
User.findAll({
    where: {
        firstName: { [Op.regexp]: keyword };
    }
})
```