# Sequelize query to find if a string contains part of the value in column

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to write a Sequelize.js query to find items where the column value is contained within an input string.

For example, if I had a table with a column with the values `Apple, Banana, Orange` and my search term was `Apple Pie` then the query would return the row for `Apple`.

This seems to be possible in SQL ([SQL - Query to find if a string contains part of the value in Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389293/sql-query-to-find-if-a-string-contains-part-of-the-value-in-column)), but I am unsure how I would write this query with Sequelize ORM.

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533244/sequelize-typescript-querying-if-string-contains-word
and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352090/sequelize-find-all-that-match-contains-case-insensitive