# sequelize-typescript querying if string contains word

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I m using Nestjs + sequelize-typescript  + postgresql.
I would like to select rows in table that content contains specific word. this is my code :

```js
async findUsers(searchedWord: string): Promise<users[]> {
  return await this.USER_REPOSITORY.findAll({
   attributes: [ 'id', 'name' ],
   where: {
    content: '%'+ searchedWord +'%'
   },
   order: [ [ 'id', 'ASC' ] ]
  });
 }
}
```

but this method didn't work ! Any suggestions ?

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: "Didn't work" is a very generic thing to say. What about it didn't work? The query errored due to bad syntax? The query didn't return the expected data? Have you checked what SQL is being executed via logging the query?

Comment: i mean that it return empty array

Comment: this is the SQL query executed via logging (default): SELECT "id","name" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."content" = '%test%' ASC;

Comment: the problem is resolved , thank you for your reply