# Case sensitivity issue when searching Sequelize json object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have shared the details below. I need to evaluate the value of the firstname field to lowercase. How can I provide this?

```
const data = await sequelize.models.orders.findAll({
    where: {
      ['customer.firstname']: {
       [Op.substring]: 'Janice', // Important here 
      },
    },
  });
console.log(data.length>0) // true - gave a correct response.
```

```
const data = await sequelize.models.orders.findAll({
    where: {
      ['customer.firstname']: {
        [Op.substring]: 'janice', // Important here 
      },
    },
  });
console.log(data.length) // false gave a incorrect response
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work if the database is PG.

```
const data = await sequelize.models.orders.findAll({
    where: {
        ['customer.firstname']: {
            [Op.iLike]: '%janice', 
        },
    },
});
console.log(data.length)
```

or sequelize.where, sequelize.fn, and sequelize.col can be implemented.

This discussion may aid in determining the answer.

[Sequelize: Find All That Match Contains (Case Insensitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352090/sequelize-find-all-that-match-contains-case-insensitive)

Comment: Hi, this for PG i know thank you. But i'm using mysql 8.0

Comment: Hi, try it, please. [Op.like] : '%janice%' . [Op.substring] Has been depreciated in future version of sequelize.